# Manage Facebook login and logout in an Android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm developing an android app and I've added the Facebook login button to retrieve profile informations. It does work, but I need to manage the behavior of the application on login and logout. For example, when the user logs out from Facebook, all the activities would be closed and the application would return to the first activity where you can just login or close the app. Also, when he login back in a second moment, I would like to retrieve all the data about him of the application (so, for example, if the app saves user's settings and other stuff, all of his settings and saves would be taken back and loaded when he logs in back).
Do methods "onFacebookLogout" kindof exist in the Facebook library? Because i couldn't find anything on Facebook documentation on developers site, neither examples on the Internet. Otherwise, how can I manage behavior and saved data on login and logout?

Last, I'm wondering if there's a method to separate the Facebook login button from the logout one (keep them in different activities or fragments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the user is logging in or out take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894564/how-i-get-is-user-login-or-logout-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-1/30081877#30081877):

Notice that this would only work if you are using facebook skd 4.0.x and above.